# Windows command line utility to control network bandwidth

Tags: command-line, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

I'm looking for a windows **command line utility** (it should be command line based because I want to call it from another application) that can control network bandwidth(I mean the download and upload speed)

Comment: there is no need that the application set limits for every specific applications, it can be globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netlimiter can control the bandwidth and has an API which I think you could call from a command line script, see: http://netlimiter.com/devzone.php

Comment: tnx, i'll try that